# How worth it is to sit the 漢字検定 【かんじけんてい】 to get a job in IT?

Tags: discussion, kanji

One of my goals is to land a job in Japan as a software engineer. I have 2 years of experience in my field and I'm currently aiming to get the JLPT N3. I have been thinking of giving 漢字検定【かんじけんてい】 a try, either the level 7 or 6. Do you think it is worth taking this exam so as to impress the recruiters or to score more points at job interviews?

Thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an actual qualification it won’t do you any good; i.e., for a job that requires high Japanese proficiency, really anything lower than a 2級 won’t mean much.

However, for jobs that don’t require high proficiency, it’d probably serve as a decent indicator that you’re someone who is driven and cares about improving their Japanese. The large majority of foreigners absolutely do not take the 漢検 so you’ll definitely stand out in a good way!